# Proof by induction (summation)

Tags: induction

I need to prove that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (2k+1) = (n+1)^2$$

What I tried:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (2k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^n (2k+1) + (n+1) = (n+1)^2 + (n+1)$$
$$(n+1)[(n+1)+1] = (n+1)(n+2)$$

Which is not equal to $((n+1)+1)^2 = (n+2)^2$

Any tip? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When $k=n+1$ you have $(2k+1) = (2n+3)$ not $(n+1)$

Comment: @Henry you mean $2(n+1)+1 = 2n+2+1 = 2n+3$ right?

Comment: Yes indeed I do

Comment: Now if I replace by the Inductive Hypotesis I got $(n+1)^2 + (2k + 3)$. No idea how to continue as I now have 2 variables.

Comment: No. You have $(n+1)^2+(2n+3)$.  Expand and simplify

Comment: Alright so I have $n^2 + 4n + 4$. Then $(n+2)^2 = n^2+2n2+2^2 = n^2+4n+4$ so I'm done right?

Comment: Alternative hint: prove (by induction or otherwise) that $\sum_{k=0}^n k = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\,$. Then:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (2k+1) = 2 \sum_{k=0}^n k + \sum_{k=0}^n 1 = n(n+1) + n + 1= (n+1)^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base case: at $n = 1$ we have $2(0) + 1 + 2(1) + 1 = 4 = (1+1)^2$.

Assume that the relation works up to $n$, then $$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (2k+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} (2k+1) + (2(n+1)+1) = (n+1)^2 + 2n + 3 = n^2  + 4n + 4 = (n+2)^2 = ((n+1)+1)^2$$
This completes the proof.